# Build a protocol buffer project with Intellij. No such file or directory when the file does exit

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, protocol-buffers

I'm working on a protocol buffer project with Intellij. While trying to add a maven plugin to compile the .proto file, it says

"C:\Users\E24131\IdealProjects\testProtobuf\src\main\test.proto
Error: No such file or directory"

1. I checked the filepath. The file exists.
2. The file type in Intellij can recognize the *.proto file.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Project Structure settings > Facets and edit Protobuf Facet.
Specify output directory for compiled .java files.